# Why can't Eclipse handle @value when used in another class?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I want the string from `A_CONSTANT` to be part of the comments of `ClassB`:

```
package my.stuff;

public class ClassA {
    /** Shows the string just fine: {@value} */
    public static final String A_CONSTANT = "show this in comments";
}
```

---

```
package my.stuff;

/**
 * Does not give me the string: {@value my.stuff.ClassA#A_CONSTANT}
 * Neither does this: {@value ClassA#A_CONSTANT}
 * 
 * @see my.stuff.ClassA#A_CONSTANT
 */
public class ClassB {

}
```

The `{@value}` in `ClassA` shows me the string content when hovering over the constant's name; that's fine.

Also the `@see` tag does its job in `ClassB` by linking to `A_CONSTANT`.

Yet the two `{@value ...}` attempts in `ClassB` fail: I see the literal `{@value ...}` part and not the contents of `A_CONSTANT` when hovering over `ClassB`.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@value%7D) tells me to use the following notation which I think I did: `{@value  package.class#field}`.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426959/javadoc-displaying-value-on-an-inner-class-constant-using-value) also advises to use the above notation.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199099/javadoc-value-to-reference-field-in-other-class) is basically the same question as mine but was not answered.

How can I show the string contents of the constant in the comments of the other class?

I'm using Eclipse Juno on Windows 7 x86.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

When running javadoc.exe on my project `{@value my.stuff.ClassA#A_CONSTANT}` resolves to the correct string.

This is why I have changed the question a bit:

Why doesn't Eclipse display the constant's string on mouseover while javadoc.exe has no problem with it?

[image: Mouse over in Eclipse: Constant's string is not shown]

Comment: I'm a newb to this, so maybe a dumb comment. Ran `javadoc` and there is shows correctly for ClassB `Does not give me the string: "show this in comments" Neither does this:`. So the problem is with your Eclipse and my JEdit. Perhaps there is somewhere to specify where the generated javadoc and e.g. constant-values.html are located.

Comment: (Just tried with eclipse luna (4.4). The same result. I guess this is a bug. Or a regression: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=172459)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would appear to be a bug in Eclipse. Modifying the example slightly from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@value%7D):

```
public class TestClass {
  /**
   * The value of this constant is {@value}.
   */
  // In Eclipse this shows: The value of this constant is "<script>".
  public static final String SCRIPT_START = "<script>";
  /**
   * Evaluates the script starting with {@value TestClass#SCRIPT_START}.
   */
  // In Eclipse this shows: Evaluates the script starting with {@value TestClass#SCRIPT_START}.
  public void test1() {
  /**
   * Evaluates the script starting with {@value #SCRIPT_START}.
   */
  // In Eclipse this shows: Evaluates the script starting with "<script>".
  public void test2() {
  }
}
```

A [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490247) has been created with eclipse for this.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report.

Comment: It would be great if people could also upvote the Eclipse bug.  Might actually help prioritize the fix.

Answer (score -1):

On the javadoc reference page that you linked to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@value%7D), under "Where Tags Can Be Used" it cites that @value can be used on a field, but not on a class. In Class B, the javadoc is on the class, which is invalid. Its possible that eclipse is strictly following that evaluation while the javadoc.exe is more lenient with placement.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question nor the example, `{@value my.stuff.ClassA#A_CONSTANT}` targets the field `A_CONSTANT` inside the class `ClassA`, so it should work, but Eclipse doesn't seem to accept this syntax...